# Simple jQuery addClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this short code,

```
$("#contact").click(function(){
$("#contact").addClass("clicked");
});
```

And it is not working, returning me

> "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

, ref to the 2nd line

```
$("#contact").addClass("clicked");
```

So, jquery is working cause he is recognizing the first line, and the element `$("#contact")` is correctly named cause he is detecting the click function. I can´t guess why is that line failing.

---

After seeing all your comments,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#contact").click(function(){
                $("#contact").addClass("clicked");
            });
        });
        </script>
```

My code is just like that. I think jquery is well inserted, and its all in the head of the page

Comment: You have not included jquery library or library path is wrong.

Comment: you have not included jquery library

Comment: jquery not included or your code is before jquery

Comment: Or it is included, but in `noConflict` mode. ;)

Comment: Can you shor us your `#contact` element please?!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/wuU6rfnZ0OrNoguSqGwj?p=preview. Its working.Please check wheather your html is corrector there is other jQuery component is used?

Comment: try inserting `alert("test");` after ` $("#contact").click(function(){`

Comment: see if alert pops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have included jQuery but `$` is undefined, you may run jQuery in `noConflict` mode. Than you can wrap your code like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#contact").click(function(){
        $("#contact").addClass("clicked");
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked, I guess I have to take a look to jQuery in noConflict mode. Never eart about that. Thanks dude.

Comment: @ivannaxara - how your `$(document).ready(function(){` line was getting executed correctly then? You posted it in your question.

Comment: @vijayP the error would be the same, maybe the line was incorrect. It would not be the first time, that a line number would be wrong. ;)

Comment: @eisbehr - i just posted this because OP was quite sure about click event function getting executed but not the line inside click handler.

Comment: @vijayP yeah maybe the line is wrong, but that was what my debugger said. And I also saw that the error just appeared when I clicked the #contact element